# Can I get a virus by visiting an unknown website using python's requests package?

Tags: python, security, python-requests, virus

I'm visiting an unknown and possibly malicious website. Lots of them. Python's requests do not run javascript. Can I get infected? Should I consider using a virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, merely downloading HTTP data won't install a virus.

A virus needs to be *activated* too, and `requests` doesn't do anything with the downloaded data for that to happen. Normally, a virus uses bugs in the browser (or more commonly, a plugin in the browser) to trigger code execution, or by tricking the user into executing the downloaded file. For example, bugs in the Flash player executing a Flash file could be used to run arbitrary code, or the user is tricked into believing they downloaded a document but it is really an executable program.

Comment: Is there something or somewhere I can read to find out the majority of ways I can get infected? Maybe some book or an article or paper? What about drive-by attacks?

Comment: Probably, but I don't know what to recommend. I'd start with a search for "how do computer viruses work" and go from there.

Comment: @userqwerty1 [SE.security](https://security.stackexchange.com) has a wealth of information and expertise.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks, looking into it now. Well, paranoia, here I come!